# jQuery build gallery from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, formatting

I have an array filled with image links and I'd like to write a script that would, using javascript (with jQuery library), would format the html output like so:

```
<div id="gallery">
<div class="scrollable">   
    <div class="items">
        <div>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

After every 5 image links it processes, it will add another div container inside the items class. So if the array contained 15 image links then the end result would be something like:

```
<div id="gallery">
<div class="scrollable">   
    <div class="items">
        <div>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
            <img src="URL_from_array"/>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

and so on until the end of the array. Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry about the code identation, it screwed up when posting.

Edit2: Clarification.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this server-side rather than *after* the page was loaded ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I'd like to do this client-side for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit - I fixed the code up so that it would dynamically create more images, in sets of five.  I believe that's everything you asked.

How about this?

```
$('div#gallery img').each(function(){
    var i = $('div#gallery img').index(this);
   $(this).attr('src',images[i]); 
});
```

Try the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/926qD/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a clarification to the main post. It would need to output a new div after every 5 images it processes, I don't think your code does that (I might be wrong, I'm still a newbie).

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the affirmation.  I often try to answer questions I just recently figured out myself.  So when I saw your question I thought "I know how to do this!"  Cheers.